# Setting focus on submit button fires the bound event

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have a couple of text inputs in which hitting the enter key should move to the next one and after the last text input finally the submit button should have the focus without being pressed. Jumping from input to input by enter works fine with this:

```
$("input.insert").keydown(function (event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("input.insert").eq($("input.insert").index(this) + 1).focus(); 
    }
});
```

But when the cursor is in the last text input field just ahead of the submit button and I hit enter the focus jumps to the submit button **and** releases its click event. Why? I want the user to hit enter again after leaving the last input field.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what is happening with your code without seeing the rest of it, but I'm sure that adding the `event.preventDefault()` line will solve your problem. It basically stops the browser from carring out the default action for the event see example http://jsfiddle.net/3m4eL/

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("input").eq($("input").index(this) + 1).focus();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Note that I've only bound the function to the keydown event of the text inputs, and not the submit input - otherwise you can't submit the form at all

note that `event.preventDefault()` does not exist natively in Internet Explorer prior to version 9, but jQuery adds the missing function for you and uses `event.returnValue = false` as a fallback

Comment: That was indeed helpful! Thank you very much. Both of your suggestions were necessary to make the stuff to perform as desired. Without limiting the keydown event to text inputs, only something weird occurs: The following submit button gets a border but not the dotted focus indicator and doesn't respond to any further key. I must say that all this is really awkward. How did you came up with the solution? How can I do so? Thanx again. :o)

Comment: If I'm really stuck with something like this then what I do is strip things back to their most simplest form (that works), and then slowly add the rest back in. This just makes it easier because you narrow it down and focus on where the problem lies. That's what is so good about jsFiddle - see if you can reproduce your problem there and I'll take a look at it...